# Dashed lines not working in Google Charts Line Chart with series toggle

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have been learning Google Charts using examples on here and have created a line chart in which I can toggle series on and off by clicking them in the legend.

I would also like to alternate between solid and dashed lines for each series. However the lineDashStyle option isn't working and I can't see why. Can anyone help please?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'table']});


var dataValues = [{DateScore: '2018-6-14', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-15', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-17', A: 1000, B: 900, C: 800, D: 700, E: 600, F: 500, NrS: 400, }, {DateScore: '2018-6-22', A: 800, B: 600, C: 1000, D: 900, E: 300, F: 100, NrS: 600, } ];

var Data = {
    displayed: [...dataValues],
    hidden: Object.keys(dataValues[0]).reduce((a, c) => {
        a[c] = false;
        return a;
    }, {}),
    map: Object.keys(dataValues[0])
};


google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(DrawChartScores);

function DrawChartScores() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var options = {
        title: 'Scores',
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        colors: ['ff0000','ff0000','000099','000099','ff6600','ff6600','006600'],

        series: {
        1: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
        3: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
        5: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
        },

        explorer: {
            keepInBounds: true,
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
        },
        series: Data.map.reduce((a, c, i) => {
            a[i] = {};
            return a;
        }, {})
    };

    data.addColumn('date', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'B');
    data.addColumn('number', 'C');
    data.addColumn('number', 'D');
    data.addColumn('number', 'E');
    data.addColumn('number', 'F');
    data.addColumn('number', 'NrS');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        let newRow = Object.values(dataValues[i]);
        newRow[0] = new Date(newRow[0]);
        data.addRow(newRow);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartP'));
    var last = {
        column: true,
        row: true
    };


    function showHideSeries() {
        var sel = chart.getSelection();

        if (sel.length === 0 && last.row === null) {
            Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[last.column]];
        } else if (sel.length && sel[0].row === null) {
            // toggle the current item selected
            Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]] = !Data.hidden[Data.map[sel[0].column]];
            last = sel[0];
        } else {
            return;
        }

        vparse(data);
        options = vkillLegend(options);
        chart.draw(data, options);

    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);
    chart.draw(data, options);

}

function vparse(data) {
    Data.displayed.reduce((a, c, i) => {
        for (let k in c) {
            if (k === "DateScore") continue;
            if (Data.hidden[k])
                data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), null);
            else
                data.setValue(i, Data.map.indexOf(k), c[k]);
        }
        return true;
    }, []);
    return data;
}

function vkillLegend(options) {
    options.series = Object.keys(options.series).reduce((a, c, i) => {
        let current = {};
        if (Data.hidden[Data.map[i]]) current.color = "#CCCCCC";
        else c.color = null;
        a[i - 1] = current;
        return a;
    }, {});
    return options;
}
```

The resulting graph looks like this - all the lines are solid:

[Graph without dashed lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvCoy.png)

Comment: looks like you have two series options, can only have one

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't realised that wasn't allowed.

I've tried a few different ways to combine them but no success yet. Is it possible?

Comment: you can remove the second series option, the one with `Data.map.reduce` -- no reason to add a blank series option `{}` -- it doesn't have to exist to work

Comment: Made some progress thanks!

The chart now appears as I hoped it would. However when any of the lines are toggled off, all the dashed lines disappear.

The options code is now:

var options = {
title: 'Scores',
width: '80%',
height: '80%',
colors: ['ff0000','ff0000','000099','000099','ff6600','ff6600','006600'],
series: {
1: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
3: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
5: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },
explorer: {
keepInBounds: true,
actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
},
};

I suspect the chunk of code which was removed needs to be added back in somehow?

Comment: the dash style is being removed in the `vkillLegend` function. need to retain `lineDashStyle` there...

Comment: Thanks for that.

Okay I modified the code to add the _lineDashStyle_ back in after _vkillLegend_:

`options = vkillLegend(options);

options = options + ",1: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },3: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },5: { lineDashStyle: [4, 2] },"

chart.draw(data, options);`

However now when I toggle one of the lines off it gives this error message:

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')**

I can't find _toLowerCase_ in the code so not sure where I've gone wrong here.